# Not being able to read orientdb Id in post request

Tags: node.js, express, screen-orientation

I have a delete route which deletes a post from orientdb. The route is as follows:

```
app.delete ('/delete/:id', (req,res) =>{
```

// do something to delete the record

});

I am using express-handlebars and in my show posts table the rid for each post is display inside express handlebar  {{[@rid]}} and the id's are displayed properly. But when I click on the app.delete no I'd is passed to the controller in order to delete it.

The orientdb Id are in the form of #cluster: position and I thinks this is causing a problem when I try to pass the I'd in params in the route to node.

Is there a way to safely pass orientdb rid in parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing `req.params`?

Try logging it. `console.log(req.params)`

That's how you get the :id parameter in your url.

Source: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html